# How can I control the z order of multiple lines in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot with multiple lines, and I want to control the order in which the lines are drawn, such that certain lines end up on top of others. For example, in the below code, B gets plotted on top of A. I can reverse this by reassigning the factor levels of `group`, but this will also change other aspects of the plot, such as the colors of each line and the order of the groups in the legend. Is there any way to directly control the order in which the lines are plotted independent of anything else, perhaps through an aesthetic?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
    group=rep(c("A", "B"), each=2),
    x=c(0,1,0,1), y=c(0,1,1,0))
ggplot(df) +
    aes(x=x,y=y,color=group) +
    geom_line(size=3)
```

There is a ggplot2 manpage called `aes_group_order`, but as of version 2.1.0 it makes no reference to an order aesthetic. It appears that order was mentioned in the manpage for [an old version](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/aes_group_order.html), but it's behaviour is not actually documented, only demonstrated by some marginally informative examples.

(Edit: According to the [ggplot2 release notes](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#deprecated-features), "The `order` aesthetic is officially deprecated. It never really worked, and was poorly documented.")

Comment: you can examine the order of the grobs that are generated with `ggplot`, it is surely deterministic. If it didn't suit your needs it should not be difficult to modify to suit your taste.

Comment: Having said that, and looking at the data structure, it is not straightforward :)